# Searching value in 2 different fields mongodb + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am newbie. But I try to learn the most logical ways to write the queries.

Assume I have collection which is as;

```
{ 
    "id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "school" : [
        {
            "name" : "george", 
            "code" : "01"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "michelangelo", 
            "code" : "01"
        }
    ], 
    "enrolledStudents" : [
        {
            "userName" : "elisabeth", 
            "code" : NumberInt(21)
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "id" : NumberInt(2), 
    "school" : [
        {
            "name" : "leonarda da vinci", 
            "code" : "01"
        }
    ], 
    "enrolledStudents" : [
        {
            "userName" : "michelangelo", 
            "code" : NumberInt(25)
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to list occurence of a `key` with their corresponding `code` values.

As an example `key` : `michelangelo`

To find the occurence of the key, I wrote two differen `aggregation` queries as;

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$school"},
    {$match : {"school.name" : "michelangelo"}},
    {$project: {_id: "$id", "key" : "$school.name", "code" : "$school.code"}}
])
```

and

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$enrolledStudents"},
    {$match : {"enrolledStudents.userName" : "michelangelo"}},
    {$project: {_id: "$id", "key" : "$enrolledStudents.userName", "code" : "$enrolledStudents.code"}}
])
```

the result of these 2 queries return what I want as;

```
{ "_id" : 1, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : "01" }
{ "_id" : 2, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : 25 }
```

One of them to search in `enrolledStudents`, the other one is searching in `school` field.

Can these 2 queries reduced into more logical query? Or is this the only way to do it?

ps: I am aware that database structure is not logical, but I tried to simulate.

**edit**
I try to write a query with find.

```
db.test.find({$or: [{"enrolledStudents.userName" : "michelangelo"} , {"school.name" : "michelangelo"}]}).pretty()
```

but this returns the whole documents as;

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "school" : [
        {
            "name" : "george",
            "code" : "01"
        },
        {
            "name" : "michelangelo",
            "code" : "01"
        }
    ],
    "enrolledStudents" : [
        {
            "userName" : "elisabeth",
            "code" : 21
        }
    ]
}
{
    "id" : 2,
    "school" : [
        {
            "name" : "leonarda da vinci",
            "code" : "01"
        }
    ],
    "enrolledStudents" : [
        {
            "userName" : "michelangelo",
            "code" : 25
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mongo 3.4**

`$match` - This stage will keep all the `school` array and `enrolledStudents` where there is atleast one embedded document matching both the query condition

`$group` - This stage will combine all the `school` and `enrolledStudents` array to 2d array  for each `_id` in a group.

`$project` - This stage will `$filter` the `merge` array for matching query condition and `$map` the array to with new labels `values` array.

`$unwind` - This stage will flatten the array.

`$addFields` & `$replaceRoot` - This stages will add the `id` field and promote the `values` array to the top.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {$or: [{"enrolledStudents.userName" : "michelangelo"} , {"school.name" : "michelangelo"}]}},
    {$group: {_id: "$id", merge : {$push:{$setUnion:["$school", "$enrolledStudents"]}}}},
    {$project: {
        values: {
              $map:
                 {
                   input: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: {"$arrayElemAt":["$merge",0]},
                                as: "onef",
                                cond: {
                                    $or: [{
                                        $eq: ["$$onef.userName", "michelangelo"]
                                    }, {
                                        $eq: ["$$onef.name", "michelangelo"]
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                   as: "onem",
                   in: { 
                         key : { $ifNull: [ "$$onem.userName", "$$onem.name" ] },
                         code : "$$onem.code"}
                 }
            }
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$values"},
    {$addFields:{"values.id":"$_id"}},
    {$replaceRoot: { newRoot:"$values"}}
])
```

Sample Response

```
{ "_id" : 2, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 1, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : "01" }
```

**Mongo <= 3.2**

Replace last two stages of above aggregation with `$project` to format the response.

```
{$project: {"_id": 0 , id:"$_id", key:"$values.key", code:"$values.code"}}
```

Sample Response

```
{ "_id" : 2, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : 25 }
{ "_id" : 1, "key" : "michelangelo", "code" : "01" }
```

You can use `$redact` instead of `$group` & `match` and add `$project` with `$map` to format the response.

`$redact` to go through a document level at a time and perform `$$DESCEND` and `$$PRUNE` on the matching criteria.

The only thing to note is usage of `$ifNull` in the first document level for `id` so that you can `$$DESCEND` to embedded document level for further processing.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $redact: {
            $cond: [{
                $or: [{
                    $eq: ["$userName", "michelangelo"]
                }, {
                    $eq: ["$name", "michelangelo"]
                }, {
                    $ifNull: ["$id", false]
                }]
            }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            id:1,
            values: {
              $map:
                 {
                   input: {$setUnion:["$school", "$enrolledStudents"]},
                   as: "onem",
                   in: { 
                         key : { $ifNull: [ "$$onem.userName", "$$onem.name" ] },
                         code : "$$onem.code"}
                 }
            }
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$values"},
    {$project: {_id:0,id:"$id", key:"$values.key", code:"$values.code"}}
])
```